# want to Route between pages but don't want to change the url in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently, I am in

```
http://localhost:3000/?servicekey=kuazqvyj&lang=en
```

When I click on a button in react I put

```js
history.push("/questions", { ...data });
```

but it changes the URL into

```
http://localhost:3000/questions
```

which I don't want. I want to route but don't want to change the url.

Comment: What is the point of a route transition that isn't actually a transition? What routing/navigation library is your application using? Would simply updating state on the page your *already* on be a better use case?

Comment: i am using react-router-dom, i just don't want to change the url of application

Comment: If you don't want to navigate to a new page then don't use `history.push`. With react-router-dom navigating to the current route/path with the same parameters is a non-op. If you are staying on the same path then perhaps a navigation action isn't the correct logic. Could you provide us a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do them by using the State object and adding in ternary operators to your JS snippets in your react app, and you can change like that, but it is not a preferred approach, but here you go

```js
import {useState, React} from 'react';

let [info, setInfo] = useState(true);

if(info){
  return(
   <div>
     This says info is true
   </div>
  )
} else {
  return(
   <div>
    This says info is false
   </div>
)
```

So you can set the state using a button or so and you can do the rest, I have also used this idea in my project and as it was for a small section it did fine :)